# How to use XHR API in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512499/html-rendering-on-server-with-node-js)

Suppose I've some `javascript` code, which runs fine on client (in a browser). This code makes a lot of `XHR` calls using the browser API.

Now I would like to run this code in `node.js`. Does `node.js` provide the `XHR` API as in browser ?

Comment: On the server you can simply read the file using `fs.readFile`.

Comment: You can try to create XHR Api using fs.readFile

Comment: `fs.readFile()` has nothing to do with XHR. If you want an XHR shim for node, there are several modules on npm that do that. However you should be aware that the entire API may not be the same, for example there would be no synchronous API because node only has async network I/O.

Comment: fs has asbolutely nothing to do with making an HTTP request, and despite what some may think, you absolutely do not need to install the "request" module--Node already has an API for this: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: @mscdex most ajax request (unless it's CORS) get files from the same server so you can get them using `fs.readFile()`. You don't need http request to get those files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Natively Node.js does not provide the browser XHR API. There is, however, a node module [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) that does.

If the file is on the server itself, you can use the fs.readFile or fs.readFileSync.

If it is on a remote server, then you can do an asynchronous XHR type request using a module like request: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request. This requires some rewriting of code.

Probably the least re-writing of your client-side code will be if you use the [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) node module. It implements the browser XHR API for node.

Answer (score 22):

You don't really need an **XHR**, since you can use **http.request** that comes natively with **NodeJS**, with it you can send **GET**, **POST** and **PUT** requests with headers and body.

Here is the link to the documentation [http.request](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest).

Answer (score 1):

this is why we use `Axios` for modules. It can be used on client or server side without any dependency or code changes.

Answer (score 1):

[node-XMLHttpRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)

example code in **nodejs**

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest

/* --- */

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open( 'GET',  'https://example.com' )

xhr.onload = function() {
    
    if ( xhr.status == 200 ) {
        
        console.log( xhr.responseText )
        
    } else {
        
        console.log( `Error: ${xhr.status}` )
        
    }
}

xhr.send()
```

[replit](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Nodejs-XMLHttpRequest#index.js)

[replit callback](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Nodejs-XMLHttpRequest-Callback#index.js)

[replit promise](https://replit.com/@antelove19/Nodejs-XMLHttpRequest-Promise#index.js)

[replit Async/Await](https://replit.com/@antelove19/NodeJS-XMLHttpRequest-AsyncAwait#index.js)